# what lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.error.FetchError$DownloadingArtifacts: Error fetching artifacts: means?

Tags: scala, sbt

I got the project from github, and the import lines in file `build.sbt`been red.

I have `scala 2.11.11`,`sbt 1.3.4` locally,

then I import the project through sbt mode in idea, and fetch this error

```
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\TF\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[error] lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.error.FetchError$DownloadingArtifacts: Error fetching artifacts:
[error] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12.10/scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar: wrong checksum: C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.12.10\scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar (expected SHA-1 33e91b29dff873755751bfc45e916a16100ec818 in C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.12.10\.scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar__sha1, got 6b90283a806731d3d30386b873714d604ce1211c)
[error] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/4.5.0/jna-platform-4.5.0.jar: wrong checksum: C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\4.5.0\jna-platform-4.5.0.jar (expected SHA-1 ab163522ed76eb01c8c9a750dedacb134fc8c0 in C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\4.5.0\.jna-platform-4.5.0.jar__sha1, got 5e614ebb3050fcfce98902e857c7825900d063f8)
[error] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12.10/scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar: wrong checksum: C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.12.10\scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar (expected SHA-1 14cb7beb516cd8e07716133668c427792122c926 in C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.12.10\.scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar__sha1, got 15f27a3e414690c99cba7f4eead287e42e7921c9)
[error] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/trueaccord/scalapb/scalapb-runtime_2.12/0.6.0/scalapb-runtime_2.12-0.6.0.jar: wrong checksum: C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\com\trueaccord\scalapb\scalapb-runtime_2.12\0.6.0\scalapb-runtime_2.12-0.6.0.jar (expected SHA-1 236b392defb3823154ddd4e45b03f7832b019fb1 in C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\com\trueaccord\scalapb\scalapb-runtime_2.12\0.6.0\.scalapb-runtime_2.12-0.6.0.jar__sha1, got 81a72b03a7d67bec691584d7e4d64615a436cf59)
[error]
[error]     at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.Artifacts$.$anonfun$fetchArtifacts$8(Artifacts.scala:268)
[error]     at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.util.Task$.$anonfun$flatMap$2(Task.scala:14)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:307)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] Caused by: lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.ArtifactError$WrongChecksum: wrong checksum: C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.12.10\scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar (expected SHA-1 33e91b29dff873755751bfc45e916a16100ec818 in C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.12.10\.scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar__sha1, got 6b90283a806731d3d30386b873714d604ce1211c)
[error]     at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.FileCache.$anonfun$validateChecksum$4(FileCache.scala:702)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
[error]     at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
[error]     at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (update) lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.error.FetchError$DownloadingArtifacts: Error fetching artifacts:
[error] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12.10/scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar: wrong checksum: C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.12.10\scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar (expected SHA-1 33e91b29dff873755751bfc45e916a16100ec818 in C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.12.10\.scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar__sha1, got 6b90283a806731d3d30386b873714d604ce1211c)
[error] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/4.5.0/jna-platform-4.5.0.jar: wrong checksum: C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\4.5.0\jna-platform-4.5.0.jar (expected SHA-1 ab163522ed76eb01c8c9a750dedacb134fc8c0 in C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\4.5.0\.jna-platform-4.5.0.jar__sha1, got 5e614ebb3050fcfce98902e857c7825900d063f8)
[error] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12.10/scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar: wrong checksum: C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.12.10\scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar (expected SHA-1 14cb7beb516cd8e07716133668c427792122c926 in C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.12.10\.scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar__sha1, got 15f27a3e414690c99cba7f4eead287e42e7921c9)
[error] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/trueaccord/scalapb/scalapb-runtime_2.12/0.6.0/scalapb-runtime_2.12-0.6.0.jar: wrong checksum: C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\com\trueaccord\scalapb\scalapb-runtime_2.12\0.6.0\scalapb-runtime_2.12-0.6.0.jar (expected SHA-1 236b392defb3823154ddd4e45b03f7832b019fb1 in C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\com\trueaccord\scalapb\scalapb-runtime_2.12\0.6.0\.scalapb-runtime_2.12-0.6.0.jar__sha1, got 81a72b03a7d67bec691584d7e4d64615a436cf59)
```

what that mean? What should I do?

Comment: can you remove `C:\Users\TF\.sbt\1.0\plugins` and try again?

Comment: I had the same issue. Changed sbt version to 1.3.6. Worked seamlessly. For more details, check here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5374

Answer (score 6):

I was also facing the same issue while importing Spark SQL package through sbt. In had multiple folders for spark-sql namely spark-sql 2.12 & spark-sql 2.11. When I removed them & refreshed the `build.sbt`, the issue got resolved.

In this path `C:\Users\TF\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\`
there might be multiple folders for different versions of the same package. Delete all of them & refresh the `build.sbt`. Issue should be resolved.

Comment: Deleting the whole `Coursier` folder under `C:\Users\<your_ursername>\AppData\Local` fixed the issue for me.